# How to check if a variable in a sql trigger is not null SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers

```
 AFTER INSERT 
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE 
@p_newColorCode int

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT @p_newColorCode = i.COLOR_CODE,
@p_newStateCode = i.STATE,
FROM inserted I

BEGIN TRANSACTION

IF @p_newColorCode IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO CALL_HISTORY(CALL_HISTORY_REC_NO,CHANGE_PERSON,CHANGE_DATE,CHANGE_TYPE,CHANGE)
    VALUES(@p_call_hist_rec_no,22,GETDATE(),@p_newPlateNo +': ADDED COLOR', dbo.fn_GetCodeDesc(@p_newColorCode))
END
```

For some reason when @p_newColorCode IS NULL it still enters the IF. Is there something else I need to do to accomplish this?

Thanks for your help in advance.

SQL Server 2008 stnd.

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger is not good. You should never set a scalar variable to a field in the inserted table as there may be multiple records in that table. SQL server triggers fire once for the set of data not one record at a time. This trigger will only handle one record and thus needs a complete rewrite using joins. Even if you think only one record will ever be entered, there will come a time when someone needs to do a bulk insert. IT is irresponsible to have a trigger that only handles one record inserts and eventually will cause data integrity issues.

However, but using a select from the inserted table instead of a values clause in the insert, you can solve your problem by using a where clause to include only records where the field is not null.

Comment: Thank you for your advice and yes typically I would not do this, but in this case the program can never insert or update more then one record at a time so it does not matter, but i agree with you normally it would not be good to do this. As far as performance goes wont there be a hit from having to do a select for each field. because there are more then just one i just put one for simplicity, but there could be 40 fields that need to be checked. thank you again for your suggestions.

Comment: Databases get inserted into by mechanisms other than the application. You can never assume that only one record will get inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok in my case i should have used the profiler before posting this question that is how you check for null on a variable, but in my case there was a 0 that was being supplied from the program in place of the null. Thanks for your help and suggestions.